# Delegate functions in Async queries in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2016

I have an HTML page that is embedded as a webpart in Sharepoint (on-prem).

The page consists of a list of `Categories` and for every category , a list of  `Requests`.

e.g

```
 1. Category Name: "Cat 1" 
     - Request Name: "Req 1"
     - Request Name: "Req 2"
   
 2. Category Name: "Cat 2"
    - Request Name: "Req 3"
```

Until now every user was able to see all the categories and all the requests. Now I would like to hide some categories/requests depending on whether the currently logged-in user is a member of a group named `testGroup`.

This is my JS code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { 
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oGroup = context.get_web().get_siteGroups().getByName("testGroup");
        var oUsers = oGroup.get_users();
        var isMember = false;
        context.load(oUsers);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onGroupSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onError));
        
        function onError(sender, args) { 
            alert("error: " + args.get_message()); 
        }
        
        function onRequestByCategorySuccess(sender, args) {         
            var html ="";
            for (var i = 0; i < requests.get_count() ; i++) {
                var request = requests.getItemAtIndex(i);
                var entry = {
                    id:request.get_id(),
                    title: request.get_item('Title'),
                    link: request.get_item('Link') == null ? "" : request.get_item('Link').get_url()
                };
                    
                if(isMember && entry.id === someOtherReqId) {
                    // append to HTML
                }                 
           }
        }
                        
        function onCategorySuccess(sender, args) {  
                    var html ="";
                    for (var i = 0; i < categories.get_count() ; i++) {
                        var category = categories.getItemAtIndex(i);
                        var entry = {
                            id:category.get_id(),
                            title: category.get_item('Title'),
                            image: category.get_item('Image') == null ? "" : category.get_item('Image').get_url()
                        };
                        
                        if(isMember && entry.id === someOtherCategoryId) {
                            // append to html
                        }
                                                    
                        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("RequestsList");
                        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
                        query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" +entry.id + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
                        var requests = list.getItems(query);
                        context.load(requests);
                        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onRequestByCategorySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onError));              
                    }
            }
            
        function onGroupSuccess(sender, args) {
            var oEnumerator = oUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (oEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oUser = oEnumerator.get_current();
                if(oUser.get_id() === _spPageContextInfo.userId) 
                    isMember = true;
            }
            
            var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("CategoriesList");
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml("<View><Query></Query></View>");
            var categories = list.getItems(query);
            context.load(categories);
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onCategorySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onError));
        }
});
```

An exception is thrown stating that `get_count()` is undefined. I assume it's because the `categories` variable is null.
My question is why? Does it have something to do with the delegate functions?
But then again, why is it that the `oUsers` is not null when `onGroupSuccess` is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Because `oUsers` variable is in global scope and `categories` is not.

Comment: I thought if I use delegated functions , then the need for global variables would be eliminated. Anyway, I moved both categories and requests to global scope but now I'm getting CollectionHasNotBeenInitialized on requests variable.

Comment: Ok. After put variables in global context, please, initialize with `this.` prefix, for example: `this.categories` and `this.requests` and test again. I'll waiting your feedback.